# Can't figure out a join query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, left-join

I have a table called **products** and one **product_taxonomies**
product_taxonomies has product_id and taxonomy_id fields
I'm trying to get the product that has multiple product_taxonomies linked to it.
Using:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" right outer join product_taxonomies on product_taxonomies.product_id = products.id WHERE "product_taxonomies"."taxonomy_id" = $1 AND "product_taxonomies"."taxonomy_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["taxonomy_id", 39], ["taxonomy_id", 29], ["LIMIT", 10]]
```

I can't get the products that have both those taxonomy_ids. If I use where taxonomy_id in [29,39] it will return any product that has any of those, not both at the same time.
I tried with all the joins i know.
This is done in Rails, but could use an SQL reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do not see why you are using an outer join.

Second, when you join to `product_taxonomies`, you are asking for a record where `taxonomy_id` has two different values.  Such a record cannot exist.

I think what you want is to join twice into `product_taxonomies` something like this:

```
select p.*
  from products p
       join product_taxonomies t1 
         on t1.product_id = p.id
        and t1.taxonomy_id = $1
       join product_taxonomies t2
         on t2.product_id = p.id
        and t2.taxonomy_id = $2
```

If you want to make this more extensible for lists of `taxonomy_id` values, please say so in the comments.

Comment: That works perfectly. I was trying to use it in Rails, and nothing worked, but just the sql seems to do what i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY clause to get all products which need multiple  taxonomy_id attached to them

```
SELECT "products".id FROM "products" 
right outer join product_taxonomies 
    on product_taxonomies.product_id = products.id
WHERE
"product_taxonomies"."taxonomy_id" IN ($1, $2)
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "product_taxonomies"."taxonomy_id" )=2
```